# What are more new Features and issues of SharePoint 2016? I found some new features as I mentioned below but I need some more features details

Tags: 2016

As per my Understanding here is some features of SharePoint 2016.Please Share more SharePoint 2016 Features and issues.

**1.Large file support**

We can now upload and download files up to 10GB! Earlier versions of SharePoint didn’t support uploading or downloading files that are larger than 2GB.

**2.Durable Links**

It is now possible to retain links when you move or rename documents in SharePoint.

**3.Customized Web Parts**

If we have ‘server-side’ web parts created in SharePoint 2010 or 2013 and need to upgrade the web parts to SharePoint 2016, some may work but if we find incompatibility, we may need to update code base. In that case, we need to download and install the Microsoft Office Developer Tools Preview for Visual Studio 2015 and we will see the SharePoint 2016 templates to use and update any depreciated namespaces and code in use.

**4.Fast Site Collection Creation**

We can create site collections and sites using the Fast Site Collection Creation. It offers templates at the same SQL Server level to reduce round trips needed between the SQL servers and SharePoint.

**5.Hybrid in SharePoint 2016**

We can now integrate on-premises farm with Office 365 that will allow we to use cloud at our own pace. We can allow our users to follow SharePoint Online and SharePoint Server sites in a consolidated list.

**6.Redesigned menus, right-click enabled**

We can now right-click a file to get to the commands we most often, such as Download, Open, Share, Rename, Delete, and more.

**7.Special Characters support in file names**

It is now possible to use some special characters in the file naming conventions, which were not available in previous versions.

Use special characters such as &, ~, {, and } in file names that include a GUID, leading dots, or are longer than 128 characters now supported.

NOTE: Characters such as % and # can’t be used in file names yet.

**8.Open Document Format**

The new version now supports Open Document Format(ODF) files.

**9.Accessibility**

Here are new accessibility features for the document library. We can find improvements for alt text for every major navigation link to make easier to navigate pages.

New Shortcuts

Keyboard shortcuts to do the following tasks without having to use the ribbon: Like,

Create a new document Alt + N

Edit a document Alt + E

Upload a document Alt + U

Manage a document Alt + M

Share a document Alt + S

Synchronize a document Alt + Y

Comment: Have you already seen the "New and improved features in SharePoint Server 2016" -article (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346121)? For issues, or more like limitations, there's some non-Microsoft released articles such as "What Are The Limitations Of SharePoint 2016?" (http://www.portalsolutions.net/blog/what-are-the-limitations-of-sharepoint-2016).

Answer (score 1):

Your answer will result in bunch of links which you can too find from google search.

If you need to know about features of SharePoint 2016 then here are some couple of good reference.

- [New and improved features in SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346121(v=office.16).aspx)
- [What's New in SharePoint 2016: Features Overview](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/whats-new-in-sharepoint-2016)
- And many more......

If you want to go for issues then here are some couple of references.

- [6 Reasons Not to Migrate to SharePoint 2016](http://www.portalsolutions.net/blog/6-reasons-not-to-migrate-to-sharepoint-2016)

All possible bugs are mentioned here [SharePoint 2016 Builds List](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Builds/SharePoint-2016-Builds.aspx). This is something great reference you are looking for. Here all the bugs are listed if any present in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

At [Simply, What’s new and deprecated features in SharePoint Server 2016 ?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/16/whats-new-in-sharepoint-and-project-server-2016-in-simple-words/), you can explore about `34 new features` and `10 deprecated` in SharePoint 2016.

Also, you should check [Simply, What’s new and deprecated features in Project Server 2016 ?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/29/simply-whats-new-and-deprecated-features-in-project-server-2016/) to can explore about `9 new features` and `3 deprecated` in Project Server 2016.